# Brightness controls not working on a Sony Vaio VPCEH38FN

Tags: screen, brightness

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on windows 7. When I use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> alongside the key to reduce brightness, or even using the system settings, I am not being able to reduce the screen brightness. What is the problem?

Comment: @JorgeCastro
it is sony vaio VPCEH38FN, but i dont know how it shud help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Brightness doesn't change on Sony laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186002/brightness-doesnt-change-on-sony-laptop)

Answer (score 3):

Run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Update these lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

... with the following arguments:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: hey..this is not working for me..Instead my Fn key has completely stoppd working, first it showed the brightness bar, but the brightness just didnt reduce..Now, it is not even showing the brightness level when I press the Fn key alongside key to reduce brigtness.

Comment: It worked on my system with the 2 modifications on one line: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

Answer (score 1):

I have a SONY VPCEG Vaio and to manipulate brightness in Ubuntu. Based on a article that I lost, I use this:

https://github.com/ricardodani/sony-vpc-brightness-linux/blob/master/bright.py

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i fixed mine :

LCD Brightness Control

Once you have installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers as suggested above, you may notice that your brightness control keys do not work properly. This is fixable by editing one's xorg.conf file. Open a terminal window and type the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This will open your X server configuration (after prompting for your password). You should see a section titled "Device" that looks as follows:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Append a line so it appears like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "nvidia"
        Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
        Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

You will need to restart your graphical server (or reboot) for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same problem and I solved it as follows.*

[This page](http://herouxapps.com/wordpress/archives/9944) shows how to set up the 3D cube and I am enclosing it because I used the same tool: CompizConfig Settings Manager.

That page tells you what to install and how to do it. Once it's installed, open CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to **Accessibility** > **Opacity**. Click on the **Brightness and Saturation**/**Brightness** tab.

Enable "Increase and Decrease Brightness" and set the key combination for it. ***Be careful. CompizConfig Settings Manager is a very powerful tool and if you don't know what you are doing, you may damage your Ubuntu system.***

I would have posted screenshots but it is prohibited to new users. It is fairly simply though.

Comment: Can you post the screenshots elsewhere and link here...so someone eventually come and modify this post to include it in your answer

Comment: hey christos, this is not working for me..i did exactly wt u said, but nothing is happening..

Comment: @christos If you post a comment with link(s) to screenshot(s), and you ping me in the comment (by including the string `@EliahKagan`), I'll put them in this answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for it...**Brightness And Lock**

[image]

[image]

Comment: but u dont have the option to reduce or increase the brightness in this app..

Comment: I've edited the answer with a pic...you can see the brightness slider...

Comment: is this in 12.04, cause i am not being able to see one...

Comment: post the screenshot of your system settings on some image service like imgur...post that link here

Comment: OK. Hold on deostroll.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Pt9K2. Here it is

Comment: May be you should update your post citing this difference...and regtag your post with `12.04`, `driver` and `support`. Mention is a sony and publish its configuration out here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a SONY Vaio E15 ( E15113 ) and was able to solve the problem using the solution mentioned in an earlier post

https://github.com/ricardodani/sony-vpc-brightness-linux/blob/master/bright.py

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.