# Ubuntu 12.04 - Brightness controls not working

Tags: grub2, display, brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screen Brightness not adjustable for Acer Aspire S3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75219/screen-brightness-not-adjustable-for-acer-aspire-s3)

Controls from "Brightness and Lock" were not working so I've tried a solution that involved changing grub, which I'm detailing below:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

After doing this, the brightness control disappeared like you can see [image]

Any ideas? Would love to be able to configure Brightness or even use apps like F.lux to regulate it automatically.

Edit: I've modified the following line to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=" and now the brightness controls are back, but whatever I change the brightness remains the same. Just in case I'm using Intel H77

Comment: possible duplicate, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75219/screen-brightness-not-adjustable-for-acer-aspire-s3/78239#78239) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148884/brightness-controls-not-working-on-a-sony-vaio-vpceh38fn/148946#148946) (these also provide a better solution than the one suggested).

Answer (score 0):

See [the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/a/166470/76089). It uses xbacklight and runs `xbacklight -set X` as a startup program.

Comment: Thanks Eliah! I ended up using `xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1` to be able to adjust brightness. Hope Intel drivers get updated so I can adjust it through the GUI!

Comment: Use [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/) app. It has GUI that works with xrandr.