# Screen flickering on Dell XPS when using mid-range brightness values

Tags: 12.04, dell, intel-graphics, brightness, xps

After a fresh install of Ubuntu, I discovered the function keys for screen brightness control (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in that case) are not functioning. Digging around here, I managed to get them to work by following a solution suggested on [several](https://askubuntu.com/a/78239/86380) [posts](https://askubuntu.com/a/148946/86380), but alas — after applying it, a strange problem occurred:

When setting the brightness level to any value other than minimum or maximum, the screen starts flickering back and forth from the selected level to full brightness, apparently due to [Dell's power saver](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/notebooks/dell/xps_14_l421x_ultrabook_review/429607) attempting to dim the screen to auto-adjust brightness levels.

I looked up for a solution here on the site, and possibly everywhere, with no avail. Also tried:

- To manually control the brightness by configuring the [ACPI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight) level (setting values by `echo [some_value] | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/[vendor]_backlight/[some_key]`, without success.
- Installing the Intel graphics driver, thinking it's missing. Realized it's installed out of the box by installing Mesa Utils.

How to resolve this?

---

### Environment

- **Model:** Dell Studio XPS 13
- **OS:** Windows 7 64bit / Ubuntu 12.04 32bit (dual boot)
- **Graphics Driver:** Intel HD 3000 (Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2)
- `lshw -C display` output:

  ```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:2000(size=64)
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Mario Limonciello*](https://launchpad.net/~superm1) was probably the first to alert on this issue, in the [#954661](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/954661) bug report, complaining that:

> ... At max brightness (what it boots by default) no
>   discernable difference. Then when the screen goes into idle after a
>   few minutes not on AC it starts flickering at me violently. The same
>   thing happens if I manually hit the brightness down keys. The lower
>   the brightness the more aggressive the flicker until I go to zero
>   brightness when the flicker goes away.

[*Kamal Mostafa*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KamalMostafa) from the *Canonical Hardware Enablement Team*, released an update for the **[Sputnik Kernel PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/sputnik-kernel/+packages)** that fixes those issues (probably related to all Intel Graphics based models).

To install it, use the advanced packaging tool via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/sputnik-kernel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux
```

Than restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: hold on... it just started doing it again... :/